# Rollback entire changeset is saying there are no changes to rollback

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm using vs.net 2010, and when I right click on a change set when viewing history, I have the option that reads 'Rollback entire changeset'.

When I click on it, it says 'there are no changes to rollback'.

If I compare the changeset I want to rollback with a previous changeset, I do indeed see differences in the files.

What could the issue be?

This is the latest changeset which I basically just want to delete or rollback, how can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are these changes made by another user? If so then this might apply:

> make sure you Get Latest Version of the files first otherwise you will
>   receive a "TF204003: No changes to roll back." error

*Community content* from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That means you already have a change pended on that file.  Undo the changes in your workspace, make sure you have run Get Latest Version and then try to pend the rollback.

Answer (score 0):

For case someone is facing the same problem as me: I was trying to do the rollback on other branch. Obviously it won't work. :)